# print only specific elements on a web page

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries, bootstrap-5

I have read many topics about this, but still not working for me.

On my webpage I want to hide some elements when the user prints the page.

I am using Bootstrap 5, which has this in CSS:

```
@media print{.d-print-none{display:none!important}}
```

Then in HTML I just used it e.g. `<div class="d-print-none">Some text</div>`

But after I press CTRL+P, all the text is there ready to print.

I also created my own CSS

```
  @media print{
    
    .noprint{
        display: none !important;;
    }
 }
```

Still no luck, the elements are not hiding when trying to print them. Any suggestion?

Comment: It's worked for me, are you sure another class didn't overwrite on this class or some thing didn't messed up?

Comment: I am sure I have not such a class defined anywhere else, after CTRL+P in my browser it shows the print preview and no element is hidden, even if it has that class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so for some reason only this solution is working for me:

If I define `<link  rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print" />`

and inside that CSS I put

```
.noprint{
        display: none !important;;
    }
```

Maybe the reason is that for all CSS links I have `media="screen"` and that's why inside the `@media print` is ignored.

That's why using separate `<link  rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print" />` probably works.